# UITableView with Editable Cell Graphics

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am working in xCode 7 Beta / Swift. I have created a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController` in the storyboard. I have a controller that implements the `UITableViewDelegate` and the `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

In the storyboard, there is only one prototype cell. It has only one subview, a `UIScrollView`. In the controller, I need to add images to this scrollview. There are a variable number of images that need to be added depending on the cell. I also need to add a button to the cell outside of the scrollview. Upon pressing this button, I need to add or remove images from the scrollview, and change the button to a different button.

Currently, I am implementing all of this functionality in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Upon pressing a button, I call `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` for the row in which the button was pressed. I have a giant `if-else` inside of `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` that checks whether it is being called because a button was just pressed, or if it is being called because a new cell needs to be generated.

This does not work. A cell does not seem to remember its previously added subviews.

**Two Questions:**

1. *What is the best way to edit the UI of a tableview cell upon
   clicking a button in that cell?*
2. *How should I layout the original (before any buttons have been pressed) cells in my tableView
   with information only accessible in the controller?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reusing cells in your UITableView, no changes saved to the cells while on-screen will persist. They will be wiped, and the cell will be reloaded as 'default' once you scroll past it again. If you're wondering what I mean when I say 'reusing', I'm referring to the use of the following selector for obtaining cells:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure Cell 
    return cell;
}
```

The selector `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` means that it will reuse or recycle cells to save memory.

Having a whole bunch of images and buttons in UITableViewCell's is a problem when it comes to this. To solve your problem, I wouldn't recommend disabling the `dequeue` method, but rather to create an array or object type from which to save the cell information.

This would allow you to store the information while the cell is not present, then fetch it using the tableView row index, and present it in the cell.

Comment: When you say 'default', what exactly do you mean? What is default? Where is the code that lays out a default cell? I ask because the cells that are on the first screen when the tableview first loads are different than those same cells if I scroll down and scroll back up (thereby reloading them).

Comment: The default cell is whatever the cell is before you modify it. If I use a standard UITableViewCell and don't subclass it, it's going to be a blank white cell about 30px high. The default cell has a UIImageView and UILabel I believe. How are you creating your cells? Are you subclassing them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I was able to solve this by updating the cell UI from within the target function of the button:

```
let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition) {

    self.eventsUserJoined[indexPath.row] = false
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
}
```

I then use this reference to the cell to update its subviews. I also store a global indicator (`self.eventsUserJoined`) variable to ensure the cell is played out correctly when it must be redrawn.